# How to make title change over time

Tags: html, setinterval

I saw a web site where the code automatically updated over 1 second. A letter appeared and disappeared on the websites  and I couldn't figure out how to do that. I would like to know how - pretty sure its called `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you can do this. I'll need more info to get exactly what you are asking for. Hope this helps.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
 document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Second Header";
  document.getElementById("title").style.color = "Red";
  }, 500);
  
  setInterval(function(){ 
 document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "First Header";
  document.getElementById("title").style.color = "Black";
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
<h2 id = "title">
 First Header
</h2>
<p>
content... blah blah
</p>
</div>
```